the file format is not supported or is corrupt react native view shot & rn fetch blob
I used React Native View Shot and RN Bloob to capture the screen and save it, the image was saved but in the saved image gallery it showed the file format is not supported or is corrupt.
const TransactionScreen = () => {
  const viewRef = useRef();

  const shareDummyImage = async () => {
    try {
      const uri = await captureRef(viewRef, {
        format: 'png',
        quality: 0.7,
      });
      const filename = `transaction_${new Date().getTime()}`;
      console.log(uri);
      saveToStorage(uri, filename);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Gagal menangkap gambar:', error);
    }
  };

  const saveToStorage = (uri, filename) => {
    const {dirs} = RNFetchBlob.fs;
    const path = `${dirs.PictureDir}/${filename}.png`;

    const imageData = uri.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, '');

    if (imageData) {
      RNFetchBlob.fs
        .writeFile(path, imageData, 'base64')
        .then(() => {
          Alert.alert('Success', 'Image saved to gallery!');
        })
        .catch(error => {
          Alert.alert('Error', 'Failed to save image. Please try again.');
          console.error(error);
        });
    } else {
      Alert.alert('Error', 'Image data is empty. Unable to save.');
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.header}>Transaction Details</Text>
      <View style={styles.transactionContainer} ref={viewRef}>
        <Text style={styles.header}>Transaction Details</Text>
        <View style={styles.transactionContainer}>

I want the saved image to match the screen captured with rn view shot.
